# File uploading into server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I am making a website having image upload module.In my localhost server its working perfectly. That means i can upload images and save it. But when i host my solution i am getting a error. That is, Access to the path is denied.

This is the code i have used...

```
string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
string uploadFolderPath = "~/up_foto/";
string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(uploadFolderPath);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath + "\\" + fileName);`
```

What the wrong in this.. Please help me....
Thanks in advance....

Comment: 1.) Use `Path.Combine(` instead of adding the strings together, 2.) does `~/up_foto/` exist on the destination server that is failing?

Comment: also check the `~/up_foto/` folder have permission for read/write..

Comment: How to check that folder having read/write permission?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there's nothing wrong with your code, if it runs locally. Instead, you have to make sure if on the host environment the user "IUSER", or "IIS_IUSER", or the like, has access (Read/Write) to the upload folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting "Access to the path is denied", Did you check the folder you are trying to upload is having write access

Comment: @user3159647 if you are having a control panel for hosting your website, there would be a folder permission section which you can use. Or If you have an FTP account and use Filezilla for uploading files, you could right click on the folder you are uploading and can give the required permissions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Path.combine or server.mappath (dont forget to add System.IO in the namespaces)

```
        string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
        string uploadFolderPath = "~/Uploads/Images/";
        string filePath1 = Server.MapPath(uploadFolderPath + fileName);
```

or

```
        string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
        string uploadFolderPath = "~/Uploads/Images/";
        string filePath = Server.MapPath(uploadFolderPath);
        string filePath1= Path.Combine(filepath1 + fileName);
```